# SQL - how to decide the update values depending on current values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column with dates in the format `0014-%`  which I want to update to the format `2014-%`.

For example, `0014-01-01` will become `2014-01-01`, `0014-02-01` will become `0014-02-01` and so on.

Can I do this with a SQL query. If so how will my query look like?

This query gives me all the values that needs to be updated

```
SELECT DATE_ABC FROM TABLE_XYZ
WHERE DATE_ABC LIKE '0014-%';
GROUP BY DATE_ABC;
```

Comment: Your date_abc is stored as a varchar, not a date type, right ?

Comment: So what's the problem here? This looks like a homework question to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing the dates as `date` and not as a string, try:

```
update table_xyz
    set date_abc = date_abc + interval 2000 year
    where year(date_abc) = 14;
```

The other answers cover the case where you are storing the date as a string (which I would advise you not to do).

Answer (score 0):

Would replace work? `REPLACE(DATE_ABC, '0014', '2014')`? Otherwise combine substring and concat: `CONCAT('2', SUBSTRING(DATE_ABC, 1))`

```
SELECT DATE_ABC, CONCAT('2', SUBSTRING(DATE_ABC, 1))
FROM TABLE_XYZ
WHERE DATE_ABC LIKE '0014-%';
GROUP BY DATE_ABC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_xyz
SET date_abc = REPLACE(date_abc '0014%', '2014'%)
WHERE date_abc LIKE ('0014%');
```